# how to do continuous action on corona in touch function?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
function left:touch(e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
         boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.1, .5, boy.x, boy.y)
    end
end

function right:touch(e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
        print("right"); 
        boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.1, .5, boy.x, boy.y)             
    end
end


left:addEventListener( "touch", left );
right:addEventListener( "touch" , right );
```

in my game I used applyLinearImpulse t0 give force to the handstand man. When I click right and left button to change x and y direction. How to increase different force for every touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do.
Save the initial x,y at start move event as `ix` and `iy`.
For every move event,
calculate the difference between `ix` and `event.x` and apply the difference `dx`.
Do the same for y-axis.
If touch event ended, nil the initial x,y `ix` and `iy`.

```
local function left:touch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
    --save the initial position of boy
        boy.ix,boy.iy = event.x,event.y
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        if boy.ix and boy.iy then
        --calculate the initial x,y with current event x,y difference
            local dx = (event.x-boy.ix)*0.4
            local dy = (event.y-boy.iy)*0.4
            boy:applyLinearImpulse(dx,dy,boy.x,boy.y)
            --boy:applyForce(dx,dy,boy.x,boy.y)
            boy.ix,boy.iy = boy.x,boy.y
        end
    elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
        boy.ix,boy.iy = nil,nil
    end
end
```

Comment: @divya you dont need to use a timer. The function above needs to be tweaked, it cannot work with a straight copy and paste into your source code because i did not saw the code at your side.